# Как забанить участников у которых нет определённой роли discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Мне нужно забанить всех участников у которых нет определённой роли, но я не понимаю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию каждый участник сервера имеет стандартную роль *@everyone*, которую нельзя выдать или снять. Она распространяется на всех участников.

Для получения объекта роли используем метод `utlis.get()` из библиотеки `discord`

```
from discord import utils
```

Для получения роли, в `utils.get()` первым аргументом передается список всех ролей сервера, а вторым указывается `id` или `name` нужной нам роли. Мы будем искать роль *@everyone* для конкретного сервера именно по названию, так как не знаем конкретного id

```
guild = None # здесь должен быть объект сервера
             # его можем получить любым доступным способом, например:
             # guild = bot.get_guild(id)
             # или просто получить из контекста команды: guild = ctx.guild
default_role = utlis.get(guild.roles, name = '@everyone')
```

Затем, в цикле перебираем всех участников сервера и **проверяем, чтобы в наличии была только эта роль**

```
for member in guild.members:
    if (len(member.roles) == 1) and (member.roles[0] == default_role):
            print(member.name) # здесь нужно банить участника, вместо этого просто выводится имя
```

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    default_role = utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = '@everyone')
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if (len(member.roles) == 1) and (member.roles[0] == default_role):
            print(member.name)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо